# Getting an error after adding a receiver in my androidmanifest, how do i fix mergedexdebug error?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

Working with flutter,my app was working fine before I added this receiver in my android/src/main/androidmanifest

THE RECEIVER WHICH I ADDED-

<receiver android:name="com.dexterous.flutterlocalnotifications.ScheduledNotificationReceiver" / >

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDexDebug'.

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\MITHIL\Desktop\mini_proj\build\app\intermediates\external_file_lib_dex_archives\debug\out

Answer (score 0):

```
    dependencies {
        compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3' 
    }
    android {
       defaultConfig {
         multiDexEnabled true
       }
    }
```

Go to android/app/build.gradle and please add above lines